# Как я могу получить выбранный элемент из DataGrid WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Я получаю `DataTable` из базы данных, после заполняю им `DataGrid`:

```
public ICollectionView Item
{
    get { return (ICollectionView)GetValue(ItemProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ItemProperty, value); }
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Item", typeof(ICollectionView),
        typeof(ViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(null));

public ViewModel()
{
    database = new DBModel();
    data = database.GetDataTableProducts();
    Item = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(data);
}
```

Привязка данных в `XAML`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGridProducts"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Item}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
</DataGrid>
```

Мне нужно получить выбранную строку из `DataGrid`, но я не знаю как это сделать.
Данные для `DataGrid` могут изменяться (разные запросы - разные `DataTable`).

Comment: SelectedItem не работает что ли?

Comment: Я даже не знаю что за тип получу. Пробовал разное, но результат всегда null

Comment: `GetType()` что говорит?

Comment: Да, уже понял. Спасибо. (Возвращает DataRowView)

Answer (score 0):

DataGrid (по крайне мере в этом случае) возвращает тип DataRowView. Дальше необходимые данные можно извлечь при помощи индексов.

Переменная для привязки (в ViewModel)

```
public DataRowView SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (DataRowView)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedItem.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(DataRowView), typeof(ViewModel), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Дальше можно использовать индекс для того, чтобы достать данные.

```
SelectedItem[0] и так далее (номер индекса - номер столбца в DataGrid)
```